# iOS 9 - Facebook fails to open installed iOS app

Tags: facebook, ios9

**iOS 9 & Facebook question**

Before iOS9, a Facebook post could successfully redirect an user to an installed app via short URL (like bet365://).
Now, in iOS 9, bet365:// gives invalid link. From Safari it redirects fine, but not from Facebook browser. This is just an example, there are other apps that can't be opened from FB.

What do I need to do in order to open an installed iOS app from a Facebook post (in iOS9)?

**PS:** I understood that now, in iOS9, if Myapp1 wants to open Myapp2, it will need to populate info.plist with LSApplicationQueriesSchemes like this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>url_to_Myapp2</string>
</array>
```

but it's strage to belive that Facebook will have to do the same with the apps he wants to open.

Many thanks!

Comment: @lonut So what is the solution for this?

Comment: Also you could support App Links which will deeplink to your app without opening Facebook web view/browser. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just got a reply from Facebook.. So my assumption was correct, Facebook needs to update their own info.plist in order to open other iOS apps with short urls..

**UPDATE:** However, I've been digging a lot and found out that you can open your app from a Facebook post with AppLinks, which works perfect. Full documentation on applinks.org.

What Facebook doesn't mention is that you need scrape the website you modify, in order for changes to take effect. One way to do it is to copy paste the website address in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and apply "Fetch new scrape information", otherwise it won't work.

Comment: So iOS 9 just broke deep linking for all but the biggest apps.

Comment: @lonut So what is the solution for this?

Comment: So far, the only solution I've found is to open in FB browser a page that tells user he needs to open the page in Safari. He will click Open in Safari option from top corner of FB browser, which will open in Safari the proper page that redirects to App without a problem. Not the greatest customer experience, but at least works.

Comment: Facing the same problem.
Is there any official document which states the issue with deep linking and iOS 9.

Comment: I've just updated my correct answer above with the best option that solves this issue